# C# reading out json list containing objects

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to get an array out of some JSON code.
Which I get from here: [JSON code source](https://makertim.nl/Jacht/Get/Test)

I have this, but I have no idea how to make the output usable.

```
        //Some other code above this line
        var jsonout = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Rootobject>>(json);

    }
}

//JSON structure
public class Rootobject
{
    public Class1[] Property1 { get; set; }
}

public class Class1
{
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string tracker { get; set; }
    public string measureTime { get; set; }
    public int minAgo { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public History[] history { get; set; }
}

public class History
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public int minAgo { get; set; }
}
```

I have no idea how to to get the `lat`, `lon`, `measureTime`, etc.. from the output. Do you guys a nice way on how to do it? (I'm very new with using JSON in C#).

Comment: Do you have to use `JavaScriptSerializer` rather than (say) Json.NET? What does your current code actually do? (It looks like you should be deserializing a `List<Class1>`, not a `List<Rootobject>`.)

Comment: Your data model is wrong -- the extra level `Class1` is unnecessary.  Post your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ and you can get a corrected data model, where `RootObject` has the properties from `Class1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data model is wrong -- the extra level `Class1` is unnecessary.  Post your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/ and you can get a corrected data model, where `RootObject` has the properties from `Class1`:

```
public class History
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public int minAgo { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string tracker { get; set; }
    public string measureTime { get; set; }
    public int minAgo { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
    public List<History> history { get; set; }
}
```

And then do:

```
var jsonout = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<RootObject>>(json);
foreach (var root in jsonout)
{
    Console.WriteLine(root.measureTime); // For instance.
    Console.WriteLine(root.lat); // For instance.
    Console.WriteLine(root.lon); // For instance.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're deserializing the wrong type. You don't have a collection of `Rootobject`, you have a single `Rootobject` that contains a collection of `Class1`.

```
var jsonout = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Rootobject>(json);
```

At that point just use object notation.

```
foreach(var thing in jsonout.Property1)
{
    thing.lat;
    thing.lon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your general classes like this

```
public class Class1
{
    public string group { get; set; }
    public string tracker { get; set; }
    public string measureTime { get; set; }
    public int minAgo { get; set; }
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public List<History> history { get; set; }

    public List<History> GetListHistories(){
      return history;
    }
}

public class History
{
    public float lat { get; set; }
    public float lon { get; set; }
    public int minAgo { get; set; }
}
```

And implementation like this

```
var jsonout = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<Class1>>(json);
foreach(var item in jsonout)
{
  console.Write(item.gruop);
  console.Write(item.tracker);
  // more properties
  // and:
  List<History> list = item.GetListHistories();
  foreach(var l in list)
  {
     console.Write(l.lat);
     console.Write(l.lon);
  }
}
```